# I have a doubt about the Linux distro I should use

Tags: linux

I'm not a complete beginner, nor am I a total expert. Which Linux distro will go better than Ubuntu? I want one with which I can handle complex IoT easily and also browse the net and play games and chill. It must have a fairly good and intuitive GUI and it must also include all basic tools that a regular usage windows PC has.

Comment: Just to make sure, we are all talking about a Raspberry Pi here?

Comment: Yeah.... I posted it on the raspberry Pi site

Comment: That I did notice... Nonetheless answer are addressing desktop PC too, so I wanted to make sure. It's not like that we never get any posts that are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You want the impossible! The Pi just didn’t have the same processing power as a PC.

IoT and Desktop have different requirements, although the Pi will do either.

The only Ubuntu currently available 16.04  isn’t supported on the 3+, 18.04 is still beta.

Raspbian is the official OS and works well using a basic window manager suitable for the CPU.

Comment: Alright... Forget browsing and gaming... If there a UI better than Ubuntu? With basic tools like text editor, spreadsheet editor, etc.?

Comment: @PranavGupta53535 Why don't you give it a try? I have several distros on different SD Cards.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI is not integral to the distro (as it is in Microsoft's Windows, and often presented). You just have to install a new one.

Therefore just install Raspbian, then choose a desktop GUI. You can also install Docker to help with services.

If you want a good fast desktop, and still have Microsoft's Windows or MacOs, on your desktop/laptop, then you can install Virtual-box, and put Debian on it.